# doc file need to display doc logo near file name like whatsapp

Tags: java, android, chat, whatsapp

I tried to share document files to other person in my chat application like whatsapp. Here i want to display the file type logo near file name which type of file we are shared.if it is pdf file pdf logo, if it is doc file need to display doc logo near file name. How can i do dynamically. any default module is there

Comment: there is no default module, bundle all the file resources your app supports in the drawable and check with the extension and place the icon relatively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered this problem, here is my solution:

**Detect MIME type from file URI**

```
public static String getMimeType(Context context, Uri uri) {
        String mimeType;
        if (uri.getScheme().equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)) {
            ContentResolver cr = context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
            mimeType = cr.getType(uri);
        } else {
            String fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri
                    .toString());
            mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(
                    fileExtension.toLowerCase());
        }
        return mimeType;
}
```

**Define supported MIME type in your app**

```
public final class MIMEType {
    public static final String IMAGE = "image/*";
    public static final String TEXT_PLAIN = "text/plain";
    public static final String APPLICATION_PDF = "application/pdf";
    public static final String APPLICATION_FLASH = "application/x-shockwave-flash";
    public static final String APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM = "application/octet-stream";
    public static final String APPLICATION_DOC = "application/msword";
    public static final String APPLICATION_DOCX = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
    public static final String APPLICATION_XLS = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    public static final String APPLICATION_XLSX = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    public static final String APPLICATION_PPT = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
    public static final String APPLICATION_PPTX = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation";
}
```

**Write a method to get icon (logo) resource from MIME type**

```
private int getIconResourceBasedOnMimeType(String mimeType) {
    switch (mimeType) {
        case MIMEType.TEXT_PLAIN:
            return R.drawable.ic_text_blue;
        case MIMEType.APPLICATION_PDF:
            return R.drawable.ic_pdf_blue;
        case MIMEType.APPLICATION_FLASH:
            return R.drawable.ic_swf_blue;
        case MIMEType.APPLICATION_DOC:
        case MIMEType.APPLICATION_DOCX:
            return R.drawable.ic_word_blue;
        case MIMEType.APPLICATION_XLS:
        case MIMEType.APPLICATION_XLSX:
            return R.drawable.ic_excel_blue;
        case MIMEType.APPLICATION_PPT:
        case MIMEType.APPLICATION_PPTX:
            return R.drawable.ic_pp_blue;
        case MIMEType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM:
        default:
            return R.drawable.ic_binary_blue;
    }
}
```

Hope this help you!